# Testing siblings DNA to determine full siblings?

Tags: dna, relationship-analysis

I have done a sibling DNA test to determine if my children are full siblings or not. There was a possibility that my eldest daughter could have been her father's brother’s and not actually his.

I tested the sibling DNA including myself and the two children.

The result came back 52 percent chance they are full siblings but then said at the bottom they favour that they have the same father.

I really don't have a clue what this means because I thought that if they were full siblings then it would come back more like 90 percent than 52.

Should I conclude that they are full siblings?

Comment: Hi, welcome to G&FH.SE! Your question is likely to attract better answers if you tell us which company you tested with.  You can learn more about our site by reading our [help] center and by taking the [tour]. If your message is closed because it doesn't meet our site guidelines, you can use the edit link under your question to add information.

Comment: It would also be useful to include in the question the level of cM match between the two children.

Comment: Was this a general-purpose autosomal DNA test or a specialist one designed to test specifically for e.g. paternity or sibship?

Answer (score 2):

Full siblings will share 50% or more DNA.

Since they receive half of DNA from the father and half from the mother, they might have a combination that does not match exactly the other sibling.

You might find this [response](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/14726/determining-if-siblings-are-half-siblings-or-full-siblings?rq=1) more enlighting to learn about half siblings/full siblings.